# How to Fix Cannot read property 'click' of null Error Using Selenium and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am creating a bot with Selenium Python. I am trying to click on an element that is not visible (only visible after clicking on a button to expand a tree), so I am using JavaScript to execute a script like this:

```
entity_ID = '1200'
js = """document.querySelector("div[data-id='{0}']").click()""".format(entity_ID)
driver.execute_script(js)
```

This returns `JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null`. If I expand the tree so the element is visible, the above code runs successfully. If I collapse the tree so the element is no longer visible...the above code runs successfully. Why does this work only when the element is visible or *has been visible in the past*?

The element (within the tree) looks like this:

```
<div class="rowContainer js-tree-row AssessmentTreeGrid unselectable ui-selected treegridinlineedit" data-id="1200" data-type="15005" data-bid="0" data-role="1" data-key="false" data-testresult="0" data-strategic="false" data-released="false" data-mtallowedactions="12600,11800,8700,12000,8100,32200,32400,5400,26300,26400,32600,32500,32100,19500" data-mtunallowedactions="" data-mtunallowedactionreasons="" data-uiallowedactions="500,600" data-allowedreorder="false" data-collapsible="true" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
```

The full traceback looks like this:

```
JavascriptException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-332-7945dcef4da6> in <module>
----> 1 driver.execute_script(js)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute_script(self, script, *args)
    634         return self.execute(command, {
    635             'script': script,
--> 636             'args': converted_args})['value']
    637 
    638     def execute_async_script(self, script, *args):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\robotics\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the test till the click, run in browser's console:

```
document.querySelector("div[data-id='<ID>']")
```

If you see 'null' then:

1. The object doesn't exist;
2. You should wait for object is shown.